Identify a TV show in which a number of men in a kitchen accidentally die
I am looking to identify what I believe is a TV show, such as Spooks or 24, with a 2000s feel.
I can recall just one scene: A number of men, East European or Russian IIRC, are sitting around a table in a cramped kitchen in a house (not a lab). They are working. One of them drops a vial.
They die.
The camera pulls back to reveal a door, then a London street.
I think this was a UK series, but I can't recall the name. They appear to be making or readying a nerve gas and not cooking food, and I suppose it could be a basement, but it looked like a kitchen table.

Hi Tenaka, welcome to M&TV! Please have a look here and see what other information you can give.

I have a memory of something like this but they are working in a basement and they are not making food, they are making a biological weapon. Is it possible that it looked like a kitchen but was actually a lab?

No. They were working in a house, not a lab. A group of men, around a table. When one of the men dropped something, they died and then the camera pulled back to show the outside of the house which was on a London street. I think this was a UK series but I can't recall the name. Yes, they do appear to be making or readying a nerve gas and not cooking food and I suppose it could be a basement, but it looked like a kitchen table AIR

I’m pretty sure I’ve seen this but I can’t remember what it is. I think it’s from the last ten years. Might be a limited series about terrorism. BBC production.
